Dell Inspiron 15 power cable port is loose; what are my options?
My Dell Inspiron 15 laptop power cord has been yanked and jerked so many times that the interior plug has come loose, and now it is increasingly difficult to plug in the power cord. (I suppose that's what I get for using my laptop while lying on the couch.) Is there any exterior power port that can be attached to the laptop thru one of its many USB-A ports? (It's old and has no USB C port.) If not, what are my other options? Is it possible to open the laptop and reattach the interior port that has become loose, and if I do open the computer, will I lose programs, memory or data in the process? Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

BTW, there are magnetic power-cord connectors for that scenario -- they yank out gracefully. When the PC is being repaired, ask about having one added in series, or replacing the parts.

I thought apple had a patent for that, and dell's got some 1 wire protocol thing to keep out third party power adaptors

It would likely need to be soldered back in. I've had it done before - its fairly quick, but not all computer repair ships will do it.
In theory its DIYable, but if your unsure get a local shop to do it, especially if the damage is more than just the plug coming off the solder point.

if I do open the computer, will I lose programs, memory or data in the process?

No you won't. The bits won't fall out. I've opened up many PCs with no data loss, and I've swapped storage between identical laptops in the past cause one died, with everything working perfectly. Unless you blotch your repair, and everything dies, its fine.
